# JS function for swapping variables depending on user input/max values

Tags: javascript, algorithm, variables, swap

I am trying to make a simple cost estimator. There are max values for 3 different intputs. I want to make a function that checks inputed values and tries to make sure the z value is always the lowest value of the three, as long as the global constraints are met.

I have made this codepen:

http://codepen.io/FredHair/pen/Jdberw?editors=001

This is my code for the swapping of variables:

```
function retrVals() {
  var coOrds = {}; //empty object
  coOrds.x = Number(document.getElementById("x").value); //define each coordinate
  coOrds.y = Number(document.getElementById("y").value);
  coOrds.z = Number(document.getElementById("z").value);
  var min = Math.min(coOrds.x,coOrds.y,coOrds.z); //find the minimum of the three
  var temp = coOrds.z; //create a temporary variable to store the current z value
  var limitx = 241;
  var limity = 191;
  var limitz = 331;
  if(min === coOrds.z && coOrds.z < limitz && coOrds.x < limitx && coOrds.y < limity){
    return [coOrds.x,coOrds.y,coOrds.z]
  }
  else if(min === coOrds.y && coOrds.z < limity && coOrds.x < limitx && coOrds.y < limitz){
    coOrds.z = coOrds.y
    coOrds.y = temp
    return [coOrds.x,coOrds.y,coOrds.z]
  }
  else if(min === coOrds.x && coOrds.z < limitx && coOrds.x < limitz && coOrds.y < limity){
    coOrds.z = coOrds.y
    coOrds.y = temp
    return [coOrds.x,coOrds.y,coOrds.z]
  }
  else{
    return [coOrds.x,coOrds.y,coOrds.z]
  }
};
```

The constraints are:

```
  x = 240;
  y = 190;
  z = 330;
```

So I don't want to swap a value that will break that amount and I also always want to make z the lowest where possible.

What would be the best way of doing this? Am I on the right track with my code or is there a much better way?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Fred

Comment: To clarify, your values have to be less than the constraints and, if z is greater than x or y, it has to be changed to the lesser of the 2, is that correct? What should happen if a constraint is violated?

Comment: The values have to be under the constraints stated yes, but if the user inputs values that are over max values but could possibly be under those values if swapped accordingly then the values would be swapped. At the same time wherever possible z should always be the lowest value as long as those constraints are met.

Comment: I would add a seperate function later to deal with constraints not being met, I am just a bit lost at what the correct algorithm should be to check for these rules, so at the moment nothing happening but later a warning would appear or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly this if-statement should do what you want:

```
var temp = coOrds.z; //create a temporary variable to store the current z value
var limitx = 241, limity = 191, limitz = 331;
var xFail, yFail, zFail;

coOrds.x >= limitx ? xFail = true : xFail = false;
coOrds.y >= limity ? yFail = true : yFail = false;
coOrds.z >= limitz ? zFail = true : zFail = false;

if (zFail || (xFail && yFail)) { // z failed OR both x AND y failed, we cant ever handle this because if x failed then x is greater than 240 which wont ever fit into y

  // dont accept the input, z-fail can't be handled because if it doesnt fit in z it wont fit in x or y either

} else if (yFail) { // only y failed

  if (coOrds.y < limitx && coOrds.x < limity) { // can we swap x and y?
    var tmp = coOrds.y;
    coOrds.y = coOrds.x;
    coOrds.x = tmp;
  } else if (coOrds.y < limitz && coOrds.z < limity) { // can we swap z and y?
    var tmp = coOrds.y;
    coOrds.y = coOrds.z;
    coOrds.z = tmp;

  }

} else if (xFail) { // only x failed

  if (coOrds.x < limity && coOrds.y < limitx) { // can we swap x and y ?
    var tmp = coOrds.y;
    coOrds.y = coOrds.x;
    coOrds.x = tmp;
  } else if (coOrds.y < limitz && coOrds.z < limity) { // can we swap z and x?
    var tmp = coOrds.x;
    coOrds.x = coOrds.z;
    coOrds.z = tmp;

  }
}

if (min < coOrds.z) { //do we need to swap at all?
  coOrds.z = min; // set z to the minimum
  if (min == coOrds.x && temp < limitx) { // was x the minimum and was z less than the x limit?
    coOrds.x = temp; //x is the new z
  } else if (temp < limity) { // y was the minimum, was z less than the y limit?
    coOrds.y = temp;
  } else { // could not swap, would exceed limits
    coOrds.z = temp
  }
}


return [coOrds.x,coOrds.y,coOrds.z];
```

Comment: Thankyou that is brilliant. I trying to develop it further now so that if you were to input the values: x=240, y=191, z=10. It would swap z with the y to allow the constraints to be met. To make it that the constraints are always met if at all possible by swapping. Do you know how I would exactly do this?

Comment: Try doing something similar for x, y and z before finding minimum, look at the variable that doesnt fit and see if it fits in the larger fields. If it does, swap them. I am not at a computer atm so cant write code

Comment: I'm trying to but im getting myself really confused. even just the pseudo code on paper is getting me into a muddle. Will keep trying though.

Comment: [link](http://codepen.io/FredHair/pen/mJRbQa?editors=001) updated the codepen but I have got myself well confused. Thought about adding a for loop as a counter for values over max values but got kind of stuck. Thanks for your help anyway as you can see im fairly new at this but pushing to learn. F

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for not limiting the inputted values?

Comment: Yes but not in that codpen example. But I could possibly change that, Would you recommend that over anything else?

Comment: Not necesseraily, it really depends on the application itself, what you are asking is definitely possible, I'll take a look into it now.